# Plot bar graph by grouping numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, graph

I have 'price' column in my data frame ranging from 10 to $1000. I want to group rows by 'price' in range of $100. For example, 1 to 100 in first group, 101 to 200 in second group and so on, and plot a bar graph which shows first bar of first group, second of second group.
Thank you

Comment: My data frame has 40,000 rows. I want to add occurrence of price from 1 to 100 and  show it on graph.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `value_counts` with `bins` paramenter and plot:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Price':np.random.randint(10,1000,1000)})
df['Price'].value_counts(sort=False, bins=range(0,1100,100)).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]